# Populate multiselect box using jquery

Tags: jquery, multi-select, populate

i can populate dropdownlist using jquery as below :

Dropdownlist :

```
<select id="province"></select>
```

Script code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "function.aspx/provincelist",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function OnPopulateControl(response) {
                list = response.d;
                if (list.length > 0) {
                    $("province").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("province").empty().append('<option value="0">Please select</option>');
                    $.each(list, function () {
                        $("province").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                    $("province").val(valueselected);
                }
                else {
                    $("province").empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available<option>');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

});
```

File function.aspx with provincelist function :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static ArrayList provincelist()
    {
        ArrayList List = new ArrayList();
        SqlConnection con = DBclass.moketnoi();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TC_CODE, TC_NAME FROM PM_PROVINCE", con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            List.Add(new ListItem(
                sdr["TC_NAME"].ToString(),
                sdr["TC_CODE"].ToString()
                ));
        }
        con.Close();
        return List;
    }
```

How can I populate multi-select box by the same way above, please help me. Thanks so much.
(i use multi-select box plugin http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/, but I can populate with data from server )

Comment: What's your actual question then? You want a multiselect box. Have you tried repeating the pattern above with `<select multiple="multiple" />`?

Comment: @p.campbell : Yes i have included multiple="multiple"

Comment: @Hainlp  id selector is written like `$("#province")` notice the `#` sign before the `id`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using ajax to populate the select? Is the list of Providences going to change often? I noticed you're not passing any data to asp, so unless you're updating the database the list is always going to be the same.

Comment: @3nigma  : yes i noticed the # sign.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

not very clear but i think after you are done appending the options to the `select` you need to refresh it like

```
$("#province").multiselect('refresh');
```

see here http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#refresh

also instead of `.removeAttr` you can enable and disable the multi-select

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#enabledisable

P.S: you are selecting the dropdown by id and it goes like `$("#province")` **NOT like** `$("province")`

have a look at [**jquery id selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

your complete code may look like

```
<select id="province" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $select = $("#province").multiselect();//apply the plugin
    $select.multiselect('disable'); //disable it initially
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "function.aspx/provincelist",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function OnPopulateControl(response) {
                list = response.d;
                if (list.length > 0) {
                    $select.multiselect('enable');
                    $("#province").empty().append('<option value="0">Please select</option>');
                    $.each(list, function () {
                        $("#province").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                    $("#province").val(valueselected);
                }
                else {
                    $("#province").empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available<option>');
                }
              $("#province").multiselect('refresh'); //refresh the select here
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: it work with error : parent_20047 is null . I dont know about this.

Comment: But about 40 seconds appear an error : parent_2403 is null (document.write('<a target="_blank" href="http://ad.doubleclick.net/click;h=v8/3b74/0/0/%2a/w;243777584;0-0;0;65285208;4307-300/250;43388713/43406500/1;;~sscs=%3fhttp://www.spreadsheetgear.com/?ac=cp11"><img src="http://s0.2mdn.net/viewad/3229875/spreadsheetgear-free-trial-banners-300x250.jpg" border=0 alt="Click here to find out more!"></a>');)

Comment: its difficult to tell from the error but some variable in your code seems to be `undefined` for example i dont see `valueselected` being initialized or assigned a value...

Comment: I remomed $("#province").val(valueselected); . I think the multiselect.js file have issue. There are 4 error oElement is null, parent_26728 is null, parent_13432 is null, ... in 3 minutes

Comment: i dont think that the `multiselect.js` has issues does `this['Value']` and `this['Text']` return correct values? you can use `console.log(this['Text'])` and see in the firebug(firefox extension) console if it has logged the correct value

Comment: Yes i use console.log(this['Text']) and it has correct value. But still error  parent_7684 is null Failed to load source for: document.write('<script src=\"http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=2903367&PluID=0&w=300&h=250&ord=6188919&ucm=true&ncu=$$http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3b74/3/0/%2a/w%3B243287515%3B0-0%3B0%3B65285208%3B4307-300/250%3B42944389/42962176/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3f$$\"><\/script>');    Have you ever seen this error before?

Comment: it link to http://bs.serving-sys.com/..... Could you instruct me how to searching the best solution.

Comment: one thing i am certain of that this error is coming from else where form your code, try debugging the rest of your code for possible errors

Comment: Thanks so much for your strong supporting. :)

Comment: Hi 3nigma : How can i set 2 items are selected when populate multiselect. Please help me

Comment: it is advice-able to make a new question so that if i am not able to help may be somebody else will answer it so your chance of getting an answer increases ... also add relevant code to your question